# How would I go about running this loop until someone enters 0 in any position?

Tags: c++, loops

The instructions are to make sure that this loop runs indefinitely unless someone enters 0 in either the op, a, or b variables. How would I go about doing that? Because right now it can't go further than one equation inputted.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void calculate(float a, char op, float b);//used this function so it can be called later by the function below. 

int main(){
   void calculate(float a, char op, float b);
    float a, b; //variables for equation
    char op;// for operator 
    cout << "Enter your equation: ";
    if (cin >> a>> op >> b)
      calculate(a, op, b);

}

void calculate(float a, char op, float b){

  
  if (a==0 || b==0 || op==0) {
    EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
  
  switch(op) {
    case '+':
      cout << "\nAddition of two numbers is " << (a + b);
      break;
    case '-':
      cout << "\nSubtraction of two numbers is " << (a - b);
      break;
    case '*':
      cout << "\nMultiplication of two numbers is "<< (a * b);
      break;
    case '/':
      cout << "\nDivision of two numbers is "<< (a / b);
      break;
    case '^':
      cout<<"\nExponent of two numbers is "<< pow(a,b);
      break;
    case '%':
      cout<<"\nRemainder(modulus) of these two numbers is" << ( (int)a %  int (b));
    case 'v':
      cout << "The square root of the number is : " << sqrt(a);
      if (b!=0) {
        cout << "More than one entry detected." << endl;
      }
    default:
      cout<< "\nUnkown operator!";
    }
  

  }
```

Comment: Where's the loop?

Comment: @slackwing it says i tried to implement a while loop but it said that the variable "counter" is undeclared when i put it in the int main. This is what i was thinking of implementing.https://pastebin.com/6LiActiR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it works for you.

P.s I added for loop in `main` function and replace `EXIT_SUCCESS;` with `exit(1)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void calculate(float a, char op, float b);//used this function so it can be called later by the function below. 

int main() {
    void calculate(float a, char op, float b);
    float a, b; //variables for equation
    char op;// for operator 
    for (int i = 0;; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter your equation: ";
        if (cin >> a >> op >> b)
            calculate(a, op, b);
    }

}

void calculate(float a, char op, float b) {


    if (a == 0 || b == 0 || op == 0) {
        exit(1);
    }

    switch (op) {
    case '+':
        cout << "\nAddition of two numbers is " << (a + b) << endl;
        break;
    case '-':
        cout << "\nSubtraction of two numbers is " << (a - b) << endl;
        break;
    case '*':
        cout << "\nMultiplication of two numbers is " << (a * b) << endl;
        break;
    case '/':
        cout << "\nDivision of two numbers is " << (a / b) << endl;
        break;
    case '^':
        cout << "\nExponent of two numbers is " << pow(a, b) << endl;
        break;
    case '%':
        cout << "\nRemainder(modulus) of these two numbers is" << ((int)a % int(b)) << endl;
    case 'v':
        cout << "The square root of the number is : " << sqrt(a) << endl;
        if (b != 0) {
            cout << "More than one entry detected." << endl << endl;
        }
    default:
    { cout << "\nUnkown operator!"; }


    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. I also have another question: If I wanted to add another function to cover operations for inputs that only have two operators for example: " v 4" (v for square root), how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I didn't get your question please elaborate or make another question for it . and if this recent question works perfectly then mark (tick) to that so that other will get to know that you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

Use a do-while loop to make sure none of the 3 variables contains a 0. If user inputs any one of these variables as 0, ask for the input again.

```
do{
  cin>>a>>b>>op;
}while(a!=0||b!=0||op!=0);
```